# Как контролировать ввод данных во всех компонентах фрейма?

Tags: delphi, события, интерфейс

Проблема в следующем:

- Есть **Interface** с двумя методами **Load** и **Save** и свойством
  **isChanged**
- Есть множество фрейсов **TFrame**, поддерживающих данный **Interface**
- Фреймы имеют различные компоненты с возможностью ввода данных, такие как **TEdit**, **TCheckBox**, **TComboBox**, **TMemo** и возможно другие
- **Load** - заполняет поля значениями
- **Save** - записывает (только если **isChanged=true**)
- **isChanged** - устанавливается, если какое-либо поле ввода было изменено
- При записи запрос на сохранение изменений, при положительном
  ответе **Save**, отрицательном, если что-то менялось - **Load**.

В общем-то все компоненты имеют событие **onChange** в котором можно устанавливать **isChanged**, НО... Нужно рекурсивно обойти все компоненты и субкомпоненты фрейма(**TPageControl**, **TScrollBox** и прочее), чтобы инициализировать событие (или дополнить, если оно уже задано), а при загрузке все их отключать, после присваивать заново. Как-то это всё долго, медленно и не красиво.

В общем нужен свежий взгляд со стороны на проблему... Может возможно как-то глобально перехватить ввод от всех компонентов в фрейме, чтобы включать флаг **isChanged**? Можно ли во фрейме создать событие, которое будет реагировать на изменение полей ввода одного из его компонентов? Или как к такому вопросу лучше подойти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чем проблема один раз написать рекурсивный перебор?

```delphi
TControlObject = class(TAggregatedObject)
strict private
  FOwner: TWinControl;
  FEvents: TDictionary<TObject, TNotifyEvent>;
  FIsChanged: Boolean;
strict private
  procedure DoChange(ASender: TObject);
  procedure InitControl(AControl: TControl);
  procedure DeInitControl(AControl: TControl);
  procedure EnumControl(AControl: TWinControl; const AAction: TNotifyEvent);
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TWinControl);
  destructor Destroy; override;
  procedure Load();
  procedure Save();
  function IsChanged();
end;

constructor TControlObject.Create(AOwner: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FOwner := AOwner;
  FEvents := TDictionary<TObject, TNotifyEvent>.Create;
  EnumControl(FOwner, InitControl);
end;

destructor TControlObject.Destroy; override;
var
  LObj: TObject;
begin
  for LObj in FEvents.Keys do
    DeInitControl(LObj);
  FEvents.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TControlObject.DoChange(ASender: TObject);
var
  LEvent: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  FIsChange := True;
  LEvent := FEvents[ASender];
  if Assigned(LEvent) then
    LEvent(ASender);
end;

procedure TControlObject.InitControl(AControl: TControl);
var
  LEvent: TNotifyEvent;
  LFound: Boolean;
begin
  LFound := True;
  if AControl is TEdit then begin
    LEvent := TEdit(AControl).OnChange;
    TEdit(AControl).OnChange := DoChange;
  end else if AControl is TComboBox then begin
    LEvent := TComboBox(AControl).OnChange;
    TComboBox(AControl).OnChange := DoChange;
  end else if AControl is ... then begin
    .......
  end else
    LFound := False;
  if LFound then
    FEvents.Add(AControl, LEvent);
end;

procedure TControlObject.DeInitControl(AControl: TControl);
var
  LEvent: TNotifyEvent;
  LFound: Boolean;
begin
  LEvent := FEvents[AControl];
  if AControl is TEdit then 
    TEdit(AControl).OnChange := LEvent;
  else if AControl is TComboBox then
    TComboBox(AControl).OnChange := LEvent;
  else if AControl is ... then 
    .......
end;

procedure TControlObject.EnumControl(AControl: TWinControl; const AAction: TNotifyEvent);
var
  Li: Integer;
  LControl: TControl;
begin
  for Li := 0 to AControl.ControlCount - 1 do begin
    LControl := AControl.Controls[Li];
    AAction(LControl);
    if LControl is TWinControl then
      EnumControl(LControl, AAction);
  end;
end;

procedure TControlObject.Load();
begin
  EnumControl(FOwner, DoLoad);
end;

procedure TControlObject.Save();
begin
  EnumControl(FOwner, DoSave);
end;

function TControlObject.IsChanged();
begin
  Result := FIsChanged;
end;
...............
TMyFrame = class(TFrame, IControl)
strict private
  FControl: TControlObject;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
public
  property Control: TControlObject read FControl implements IControl;
end;

constructor TMyFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FControl := TControlObject.Create(Self);
end;

destructor TMyFrame.Destroy; 
begin
  FControl.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Comment: Если событие компоненту назначается и переназначается динамически, то будет не очень хорошо, поскольку контейнер будет хранить "старые" ссылки на обработчики событий. А если контролы вообще создаются в runtime - нужно будет дополнительно перехватывать CM_CONTROLLISTCHANGE или вручную вызывать InitControl.
Далеко не всегда есть OnChange, иногда нужное событие может быть не `TNotifyEvent`...

Comment: Я сейчас посоветую динамически менять оконную процедуру через SetWindowLongPtr(), но Вы скажете, что SetWindowLongPtr может вызвать кто-то еще и будете правы. Против лома нет приема. Каждый определяет допустимые риски и на них идет. Никто же не вызывает DataSource.DataSet.Free или StringGrid.Rows.Free? Хотя и могут.

Comment: Событие не обязательно должно называться OnChange. В методе InitControl можно установить любое событие. Если же событие не TNotifyEvent то придется автору, что-то придумать. В любом случае класс заточен только под определенный набор о компонент. У меня подобный механизм отлично работает на реальном проекте.

Comment: Я ни в коем случае не хотел сказать, что предложенный вами подход плох. Простите, если получилось резковато. Он достаточно хорош, но в ограниченном количестве случаев, что нужно понимать тем, кто будет внедрять подобное у себя.

Comment: Проблема не в том, чтобы один раз написать, а в том, что это будет постоянно крутиться и назначаться/переназначаться... А в общем пример красивый, спасибо. А за динамическое назначение событий "кем-то" должен отвечать "он же", если такая потребность вдруг когда-нибудь возникнет

Answer (score 1):

Один из возможных вариантов (думаю, это описывалось неоднократно):
Создаем отдельный модуль, в котором перекрываем "штатные" `TEdit`, `TMemo` и т.п:

```
unit SubControls;

type
  TEdit = class(System.StdCtrls.TEdit)
  protected
    procedure Change; override;
  end;

procedure TEdit.Change;
var
  intf: IMyInterface;
begin
  inherited; // здесь будет вызвано штатное событие OnChange, мы его не трогаем
  // а вот тут реализовываем свою логику
  if Owner.GetInterface(IMyInterface, intf) then
    if not intf.Loading then  // не знаю, есть ли это свойство, что-то типа "мы сейчас грузимся"
      intf.IsChanged:=True;
end;
```

Таким же образом модифицируем остальные используемые компоненты.
Получившийся модуль включаем в uses в interface секции после всех штатных (одним из последних). Таким образом, лежащие на фрейме/форме контролы будут реализовывать функционал из нашего модуля.

Comment: Интересный подход, завтра проверю работает ли это так как выглядит, выглядит вполне логично. Единственный минус - нужно будет постоянно расширять этот модуль при обнаружении новых компонентов ввода в фреймах, это не очень критично, но не приятно.

Comment: @Isaev Зато этот подход в состоянии работать с такими компонентами, у которых OnChange  в принципе не предусмотрен. Например - TXXXButton, способные оставаться в нажатом положении и т.п.

Comment: В принципе работает довольно исправно, даже все компоненты уже переписаны были для других целей и большая половина реализована. Но второй метод мне понравился больше, в компонентах, где onChange не предусмотрен вроде пока нет необходимости.